# AEM 6.4 asset renditions, is it safe to remove all the rendition

Tags: aem, aem-6, dam, aem-touch-ui

I have created a custom workflow model for DAM update asset. I have kept two steps only **Metadata Processor** and **DAM Update Asset Workflow Completed**

I am on 6.4 and I could see 319x319 rendition is used in content finder. Want to know if other renditions are used by any default AEM components? If used, is there any possibility to make all of them point to a single rendition?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered reliably, I have seen a bunch of code with rendition selector/suffix hard-coded. so most probably no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove all renditions, if, in fact, you do not use them at all and you display the raw image from your DAM (the only downside is that your Content Authors will lose several thumbnails, usually helpful to identify the asset they want to use). If you need image manipulation and optimization, you can review ACS Commons Named Transform Image Servlet or any other external service (Akamai, Adobe Dynamic Media).